# System diagnostic startup windows 2003: cant load usb keyboard

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a pc running windows server 2003 and in

> msconfig->general

tab selected system diagnostic startup and reboot system.

After reboot I can't use my usb keyboard or usb mouse to press Ctrl+Alt+Del.
In startup F8 key works and I can choose normal startup or safeboot but when windows load, usb devices don'twork

Answer (score 0):

its interesting that in  diagnosic boot mode you cant have any kind of communication to your server (ssh or remote desktop).
so i just stolen! a ps2 keyboard from university and it worked.
and never ever gonna choose diagnosic boot fom a remote desktop!